# Android theme/compatibility Issue: "No resource found that matches the given name"

Tags: android, firebase, styles, themes, compatibility

I'm having difficulty compiling my for SDK 17. It compiles just fine for SDK 25. I've tried using build tools (19.1.0) so that it matches the `compileSdkVersion` as well as change the versions of the `com.android...` packages to match the `compileSdkVersion`. I've tried a few other things but none worked. I would really really appreciate any help!

Here's my Manifest:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.notmyrealappid"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "5g"
}
}
dependencies {

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.0'*/

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'

compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.2.0'

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

//Added due to issue with android.support 25.2.0 update 
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0'

//Glide for images
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
//multi dex - should refactor code so that isnt necessary
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here's styles.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Theme Colors -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#568B3E</item>
        <!-- Light Green 800 -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#AED580</item>
        <!-- Light Green 300 -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#F57F20</item>
        <!-- Amber 800-->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Activity with no Title -->
    <style name="ThemeOverlay.MyNoTitleActivity" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Dark Buttons -->
    <style name="ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/grey_100</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Light EditTexts -->
    <style name="ThemeOverlay.MyLightEditText" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.MyTextDetail" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">true</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">5</item>
        <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.FirebaseIcon" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/icon_top_margin</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/icon_bottom_margin</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.MyTitleText" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">36sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.Base.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


</resources>
```

And here's the contense of my styles.xml(v21):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Lastly here is error that I receive:

```
D:\Dev files\android-design-library-master\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-ldltr-v21\values-ldltr-v21.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.

D:\Dev files\android-design-library-master\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(23) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(25) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(31) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(38) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(222) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(224) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(232) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar'.
Error:(238) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar'.
Error:(273) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar'.
Error:(330) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
Error:(182) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(195) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.
Error:(16) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(314) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification'.
Error:(326) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title'.
Error:(11, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:statusBarColor'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds'.
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(14) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(17) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(19) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(20) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches 
Error:(22) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(24) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(26) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(28) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(30) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(32) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(37) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(39) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(40) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(41) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(43) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(45) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(47) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(49) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(51) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(53) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.
Error:(59) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(61) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(63) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(64) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(65) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(67) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(112, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(116, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(114, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(115, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(113, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(110, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(111, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(119, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(159, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(163, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(161, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(162, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(160, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(157, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(158, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(166, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(169, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(171) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(173) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(175) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:(177) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(180) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:(185) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
Error:(186) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'.
Error:(187) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(190) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
Error:(191) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar'.
Error:(192) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox'.
Error:(193) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton'.
Error:(194) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
Error:(198) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ImageButton'.
Error:(199) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(201) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(203) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(205) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
Error:(209, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(211) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
Error:(213) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
Error:(214) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(216) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
Error:(220, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(226) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'.
Error:(227) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.SeekBar'.
Error:(228) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(229) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(230) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
Error:(282, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(286, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(284, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(285, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(283, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(280, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(281, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(290) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar'.
Error:(302) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar'.
Error:(315) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Info'.
Error:(322) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Time'.
Error:(341, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:stateListAnimator'.
Error:(23) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(25) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(31) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(38) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(222) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(224) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(232) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar'.
Error:(238) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar'.
Error:(273) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar'.
Error:(330) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
Error:(182) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(195) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.
Error:(16) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(314) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification'.
Error:(326) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title'.
Error:(11, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:statusBarColor'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds'.
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(14) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(17) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(19) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(20) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(21) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(22) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(24) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(26) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(28) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(30) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(32) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(37) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(39) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(40) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(41) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(43) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(45) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(47) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(49) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(51) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(53) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.
Error:(59) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(61) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(63) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(64) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(65) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(67) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(112, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(116, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(114, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(115, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(113, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(110, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(111, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(119, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(159, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(163, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(161, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(162, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(160, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(157, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(158, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(166, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(169, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(171) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(173) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(175) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to update the compileSdkVersion to match the targetSdkVersion:

`compileSdkVersion 17` does not compile

`compileSdkVersion 25` does

The configuration should be `minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion <= compileSdkVersion`

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason I thought that I had to change the compileSDK had to match the SDK of the device that I was using to test it on. It was such a stupid mistake that cost me many days and hours!